# Game Development, Collision

Tags: java, image, 2d, game-development

I'm new to the game development and I'm trying to code 2D RPG game. im using png images to create objcts and move around. So it is pretty easy to detect collision between rectngles and other simple shapes like this.

```
if(object1.collides(object2)){
}
```

what is best way to detect collision of image objects like player, or npc?

Comment: *"what is best way"* > Using an engine that abstracts it for you.

Comment: I need it for the university course and learning engine will take long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way is to create a hitbox that is the approximate shape of your object. The hitbox can be very simple like a rectangle or circle around your object, which is actually invisible.
Have a look at this example, the black box is the hitbox of Mario and you only need to check its boundaries:
[image]

But if you really need precision, then you will need to go through the pixels of an image and create the custom polygon. However, the more complex your polygon is, the harder it is to detect collision. Most of the time, game developers rely on physics engines to deal with it.

Comment: Oh, it is so simple that it is funny. Never thought of it. Thanks